# If grep fails delete the file

Tags: bash, scripting, shell, grep

Heya guys, I have this small script and i need to grep all the files and leave only the ones that contain a keyword and I'm stuck on this, any help in pointing out my dumb errors is appreciated :)

```
#!/bin/bash

server=(server1...server24)

.
.
.

for ((n=0; n <= 24 ; n++))
do
        if grep -q "KEYWORD" directory/${server[$n]}.html ; then
                echo Empty
        else
                rm -f directory/${server[$n]}.html
        fi
done

.
.
.
```

Comment: Just to be clear, i put in server1-24 here to simplify my code, actually each of my 24 servers has a different hostname, that's why I need the server array.

Comment: Your `echo Empty` is a bit confusing.  You realize you'll get that if you DO find your keyword, right?

Comment: yeah, that was just a dumb and quick way to make sure that the if statement works and doesn't do anything with the file if it finds the keyword, because in that case i want to keep the file, i just want to delete the ones that don't have the keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to make sure your count matches if you let your code do it for you in one of the following ways:

```
servers=(foo bar baz)
for server in ${servers[@]}
do
    if ! grep -qs "KEYWORD" directory/$server.html 
    then
        rm ...
```

or

```
servers=(foo bar baz)
for ((n = 0; n < ${#servers[@]}; n++))
do
    if ! grep -qs "KEYWORD" directory/${servers[$n]}.html 
    then
        rm ...
```

Use `!` to invert the condition so that it's "if the file does NOT contain the keyword, then delete it".

Use the `grep` option `-q` to quiet the output and `-s` to suppress error messages.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `-l` option for grep

```
grep -l "KEYWORD" directory/server*html | while read -r FOUND
do
   rm -f .....
   do some other processing here.....
done
```

Comment: grep -l "KEYWORD" directory/*.html | xargs -r rm -f

Comment: -L not -l for files _without_ match

Comment: Dang :) This is the best answer, as long as you incorporate both of @pixelbeat's comments. And, according to OP's requirements, change `directory/server*html` into `$server`.

Comment: sure, `xargs` can be used. But i am not going to change my answer. Since I am assuming some other processing need to be done as well.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the following:

- Separate the server names in the
  array by whitespace as:

  `server=(server1 server2 server3 ... server24)`
- The valid indices are from `0` to `23`
  (one less than the number of array
  elements). 
  So your for loop should
  be:

  `for ((n=0; n <= 23 ; n++))`
  or
  `for ((n=0; n < 24 ; n++))`

Comment: actually i do need the line because each of my servers has a different hostname, i just put in server1-24 for simplifying the code here.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do the grep for each file and then test the exit status `$?` - and fix your brace expansion.

so...

```
 for ((n=0; n <= 24 ; n++))
    do
      grep -q "KEYWORD" directory/server${n}.html
      if [ $? -eq 0 ] then
          echo "directory/server${n}.html - Has keyword"
      else
          rm -f directory/server${n}.html
      fi
    done
```

Comment: That's why it's just a suggestion (it aids readability) .. The brace expansion fixes the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

server=(server{1..24})

for((n=0; n<24; n++))
do
    if grep -q 'keyword' ${server[$n]}; then
        echo Empty
    else
        rm -f ${server[$n]}
    fi
done
```